# wxpython crashes on touch icon in task bar

Tags: wxpython

Everything works fine except when I touch the icon on the bottom bar **if it was hidden**.

Occurs during the progress of a download using *urllib2*

```
self.appendText(self.stateText, self.actualState, True)
            u = urllib2.urlopen(f['url'])
            meta = u.info()
            file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
            newFileName = self.selectedDir + f['name'].encode('ascii') + " - " + f['date'].encode('ascii') + ".mp3"
            fil = open(newFileName, "wb")
            aclen = 0
            while True:
                b = u.read(8192)
                if not b:
                    break
                fil.write(b)
                aclen = aclen + 8192
                self.statusbar.SetStatusText(str(aclen / 1024) + "/" + str(file_size / 1024) + " - " +  str(self.percentage(aclen,file_size)) + "%")
            fil.close()
```

I do not understand what may be happening, but maybe there is an error on an event? The crash only occurs in this part of code. Seems like have no possibility of "handle" this event.

Screenshot of application:[image]

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: There are not traceback.... simply show this: http://i.imgur.com/5SxuEZu.png

Comment: Do you think it is true to say that the application has not crashed, it has hung?   It appears (from your screenshot) that we are looking at a wxpython app that is still running, but is busy and not rendering anything...

Comment: @PranavSingh: did you look at the screenshot?   This application has not crashed.   There is no traceback, it is simply hung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked "what may be happening?".   What appears to be happening is that your wx app is stuck in a loop or sleep, and is thus not rendering anything, and appears unresponsive.

It would be interesting to know why you think that it is stuck in the code that you posted.   It would also be interesting to know how this works at all ... there appears to be no point during the while True loop where you yield to wx to render updates.   Thus I'm not clear on how your status updates are being rendered.

Suffice to say: if your code is either hanging on the read(8192), or in an infinite loop, it will cause it to appear like your screenshot: unresponsive.

To avoid unresponsiveness you need to yield to wx at times when you are taking a long time to do something.

A simple way to debug would instrument the code with prints to determine where it is getting stuck.   At least, put a print before and after the urlopen/u.info activity and at least one on the while loop.

Comment: You're welcome.   By all means, tick the green arrow if this solves your problem :)

Comment: I solved minutes before entering stackoverflow. I was too stupid. I must take a look at the FAQ, the manual is too coarse.

Comment: Heh heh - do I have to beg for the green tick?   If the answer is correct, it'd be nice if you'd tick it :)   Maybe when I have thousands of rep I'll care less :)